# How to add an Event identifier as a dummy variable to panel dataset?

Tags: r, events, dummy-variable

I have a problem regarding my panel dataset. My dataset looks like this: without the variable "Eventidentifierdummy". Now I am trying to create the variable "Eventidentifierdummy" so that it looks like this:

Is there perhaps a way to number the events per symbol? So for example, that each event window which is defined, for example, between -4 to 4 and occurs several times for each symbol, that this is numbered? In a way, as an additional identifier for the event and the company, so that the variable "Eventidentifierdummy" looks like this?

```
Symbol  Date        Close       Time      Event  Window    Eventidentifierdummy
AAPL    09/03/2020  66,542503   16:25:00    NA    NA        NA
AAPL    09/03/2020  71,334999   16:26:00    NA    -4        1
AAPL    09/03/2020  68,857498   16:27:00    NA    -3        1
AAPL    09/03/2020  62,057499   16:28:00    NA    -2        1
AAPL    09/03/2020  69,4925     16:29:00    NA    -1        1
AAPL    09/03/2020  60,552502   16:30:00    1      0        1
AAPL    09/03/2020  63,215      16:31:00    NA     1        1 
AAPL    10/03/2020  61,6675     09:30:00    NA     2        1
AAPL    10/03/2020  61,195      09:31:00    NA     3        1
AAPL    10/03/2020  57,310001   09:32:00    NA     4        1  
AAPL    10/03/2020  56,092499   09:33:00    NA    NA        NA
AAPL    15/03/2020  65,535603   15:45:00    NA    NA        NA
AAPL    15/03/2020  66,357545   15:46:00    NA    NA        NA
AAPL    15/03/2020  62,852345   15:47:00    NA    -4        2
AAPL    15/03/2020  64,057325   15:48:00    NA    -3        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  66,494545   09:30:00    NA    -2        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  63,557967   09:31:00    1     -1        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  64,415454   09:32:00    NA     0        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  62,2357     09:33:00    NA     1        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  64,4576     09:34:00    NA     2        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  59,457579   09:35:00    NA     3        2
AAPL    16/03/2020  58,092470   09:36:00    NA     4        2
VISA    05/03/2020  186,960007  16:26:00    NA    NA        NA
VISA    05/03/2020  184,360001  16:27:00    NA    -4        1
VISA    05/03/2020  171,130005  16:28:00    NA    -3        1
VISA    05/03/2020  182,600006  16:29:00    NA    -2        1
VISA    05/03/2020  172,949997  16:30:00    NA    -1        1
VISA    06/03/2020  160,080002  09:32:00    1      0        1
VISA    06/03/2020  175,830002  09:33:00    NA     1        1   
VISA    06/03/2020  152,009995  09:34:00    NA     2        1
VISA    06/03/2020  157,889999  09:35:00    NA     3        1
VISA    06/03/2020  148,479996  09:36:00    NA     4        1
VISA    06/03/2020  152,25      09:37:00    NA    NA        NA
VISA    06/03/2020  146,830002  09:38:00    NA    NA        NA
VISA    20/03/2020  192,203826  16:12:00    NA    NA        NA
VISA    20/03/2020  193,293752  16:13:00    NA    -4        2
VISA    20/03/2020  192,204726  16:14:00    NA    -3        2
VISA    20/03/2020  192,2396    16:15:00    NA    -2        2
VISA    20/03/2020  194,185620  16:16:00    NA    -1        2
VISA    20/03/2020  196,614289  16:17:00    1      0        2
VISA    20/03/2020  197,826200  16:18:00    NA     1        2
VISA    21/03/2020  197,49176   09:29:00    NA     2        2
VISA    21/03/2020  197,239230  09:30:00    NA     3        2
VISA    21/03/2020  198,2300    09:31:00    NA     4        2
VISA    21/03/2020  198,230028  09:32:00    NA    NA        NA
VISA    21/03/2020  197,247020  09:33:00    NA    NA        NA
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to fix this problem....

I also have different events per symbol, sometimes there are two events and sometimes there are three events for example. For example, I have two events for the symbol "AAPL" in the case mentioned above. The example dataset shows two symbols, but in my whole dataset there are more than 1000 different symbols with their respective events and associated eventwindows.

I have tried to solve it using the command "count", however it does not work....

```
Companies$Window <- as.numeric(Companies$Window)
setDT(Companies)[,Window:= count(Window)][]
```

Can you please help me to create the dummy variable "eventidentifierdummy"?

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is the dput() of my data:

```
> dput(Eventdummy)
structure(list(V1 = c("Symbol", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", 
"VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", 
"VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", "VISA", 
"VISA", "VISA"), V2 = c("Date", "09/03/2020", "09/03/2020", "09/03/2020", 
"09/03/2020", "09/03/2020", "09/03/2020", "09/03/2020", "10/03/2020", 
"10/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "15/03/2020", "15/03/2020", 
"15/03/2020", "15/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", 
"16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "05/03/2020", 
"05/03/2020", "05/03/2020", "05/03/2020", "05/03/2020", "06/03/2020", 
"06/03/2020", "06/03/2020", "06/03/2020", "06/03/2020", "06/03/2020", 
"06/03/2020", "20/03/2020", "20/03/2020", "20/03/2020", "20/03/2020", 
"20/03/2020", "20/03/2020", "20/03/2020", "21/03/2020", "21/03/2020", 
"21/03/2020", "21/03/2020", "21/03/2020"), V3 = c("Close", "66,542503", 
"71,334999", "68,857498", "62,057499", "69,4925", "60,552502", 
"63,215", "61,6675", "61,195", "57,310001", "56,092499", "65,535603", 
"66,357545", "62,852345", "64,057325", "66,494545", "63,557967", 
"64,415454", "62,2357", "64,4576", "59,457579", "58,092470", 
"186,960007", "184,360001", "171,130005", "182,600006", "172,949997", 
"160,080002", "175,830002", "152,009995", "157,889999", "148,479996", 
"152,25", "146,830002", "192,203826", "193,293752", "192,204726", 
"192,2396", "194,185620", "196,614289", "197,826200", "197,49176", 
"197,239230", "198,2300", "198,230028", "197,247020"), V4 = c("Time", 
"16:25:00", "16:26:00", "16:27:00", "16:28:00", "16:29:00", "16:30:00", 
"16:31:00", "09:30:00", "09:31:00", "09:32:00", "09:33:00", "15:45:00", 
"15:46:00", "15:47:00", "15:48:00", "09:30:00", "09:31:00", "09:32:00", 
"09:33:00", "09:34:00", "09:35:00", "09:36:00", "16:26:00", "16:27:00", 
"16:28:00", "16:29:00", "16:30:00", "09:32:00", "09:33:00", "09:34:00", 
"09:35:00", "09:36:00", "09:37:00", "09:38:00", "16:12:00", "16:13:00", 
"16:14:00", "16:15:00", "16:16:00", "16:17:00", "16:18:00", "09:29:00", 
"09:30:00", "09:31:00", "09:32:00", "09:33:00"), V5 = c("Event", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), V6 = c("Window", NA, "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", NA, NA, NA, "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", NA, "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
NA, NA, NA, "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
NA, NA), V7 = c("Eventidentifierdummy", NA, "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", NA, "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", NA, NA, NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -47L))
```

Comment: Can you please share the sample data frame by using dput()? It would make it easier for anyone to help.

Comment: Yes of course. I added the dput() of my dataset. I just called the dataset "Eventdummy" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle` to create such sequence and apply it for each `Symbol`.

```
library(dplyr)

create_num <- function(x) {
  val <- with(rle(is.na(x)), rep(cumsum(values), lengths))
  val[is.na(x)] <- NA
  val  
}

df %>%
  group_by(Symbol) %>%
  mutate(result = create_num(Window)) %>%
  ungroup
```

This returns -

```
   Symbol       Date      Close     Time Event Window Eventidentifierdummy result
1    AAPL 09/03/2020  66,542503 16:25:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
2    AAPL 09/03/2020  71,334999 16:26:00    NA     -4                    1      1
3    AAPL 09/03/2020  68,857498 16:27:00    NA     -3                    1      1
4    AAPL 09/03/2020  62,057499 16:28:00    NA     -2                    1      1
5    AAPL 09/03/2020    69,4925 16:29:00    NA     -1                    1      1
6    AAPL 09/03/2020  60,552502 16:30:00     1      0                    1      1
7    AAPL 09/03/2020     63,215 16:31:00    NA      1                    1      1
8    AAPL 10/03/2020    61,6675 09:30:00    NA      2                    1      1
9    AAPL 10/03/2020     61,195 09:31:00    NA      3                    1      1
10   AAPL 10/03/2020  57,310001 09:32:00    NA      4                    1      1
11   AAPL 10/03/2020  56,092499 09:33:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
12   AAPL 15/03/2020  65,535603 15:45:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
13   AAPL 15/03/2020  66,357545 15:46:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
14   AAPL 15/03/2020  62,852345 15:47:00    NA     -4                    2      2
15   AAPL 15/03/2020  64,057325 15:48:00    NA     -3                    2      2
16   AAPL 16/03/2020  66,494545 09:30:00    NA     -2                    2      2
17   AAPL 16/03/2020  63,557967 09:31:00     1     -1                    2      2
18   AAPL 16/03/2020  64,415454 09:32:00    NA      0                    2      2
19   AAPL 16/03/2020    62,2357 09:33:00    NA      1                    2      2
20   AAPL 16/03/2020    64,4576 09:34:00    NA      2                    2      2
21   AAPL 16/03/2020  59,457579 09:35:00    NA      3                    2      2
22   AAPL 16/03/2020  58,092470 09:36:00    NA      4                    2      2
23   VISA 05/03/2020 186,960007 16:26:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
24   VISA 05/03/2020 184,360001 16:27:00    NA     -4                    1      1
25   VISA 05/03/2020 171,130005 16:28:00    NA     -3                    1      1
26   VISA 05/03/2020 182,600006 16:29:00    NA     -2                    1      1
27   VISA 05/03/2020 172,949997 16:30:00    NA     -1                    1      1
28   VISA 06/03/2020 160,080002 09:32:00     1      0                    1      1
29   VISA 06/03/2020 175,830002 09:33:00    NA      1                    1      1
30   VISA 06/03/2020 152,009995 09:34:00    NA      2                    1      1
31   VISA 06/03/2020 157,889999 09:35:00    NA      3                    1      1
32   VISA 06/03/2020 148,479996 09:36:00    NA      4                    1      1
33   VISA 06/03/2020     152,25 09:37:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
34   VISA 06/03/2020 146,830002 09:38:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
35   VISA 20/03/2020 192,203826 16:12:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
36   VISA 20/03/2020 193,293752 16:13:00    NA     -4                    2      2
37   VISA 20/03/2020 192,204726 16:14:00    NA     -3                    2      2
38   VISA 20/03/2020   192,2396 16:15:00    NA     -2                    2      2
39   VISA 20/03/2020 194,185620 16:16:00    NA     -1                    2      2
40   VISA 20/03/2020 196,614289 16:17:00     1      0                    2      2
41   VISA 20/03/2020 197,826200 16:18:00    NA      1                    2      2
42   VISA 21/03/2020  197,49176 09:29:00    NA      2                    2      2
43   VISA 21/03/2020 197,239230 09:30:00    NA      3                    2      2
44   VISA 21/03/2020   198,2300 09:31:00    NA      4                    2      2
45   VISA 21/03/2020 198,230028 09:32:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
46   VISA 21/03/2020 197,247020 09:33:00    NA     NA                   NA     NA
```

Created another column called `result` so that the answer can be compared. You can replace `result` with `Eventidentifierdummy`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` to do the grouping, and identifying the start of an event as a -4 value:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( companies )

companies[ !is.na(Window),
           Eventidentifierdummy := cumsum(Window == -4),
           by = Symbol ]
```